# How to Consume SAP Web Service in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, abap, sap-erp

I want to consume SAP web service into my c# application. For that i wrote one block of code given below.

```
NetworkCredential ntobj = new NetworkCredential();
            ZWEBSERVICE_INTERNAL_ORDER2 zClassobj = new ZWEBSERVICE_INTERNAL_ORDER2();
            ZbapiFiCreateInternalOrder zMethodObj = new ZbapiFiCreateInternalOrder();
            ZbapiFiCreateInternalOrderResponse zMethodResobj = new ZbapiFiCreateInternalOrderResponse();

            ntobj.UserName = "alpldev";
            ntobj.Password = "alpl123";

            zClassobj.PreAuthenticate = true;
            zClassobj.Credentials = ntobj;

            zMethodObj.IDriverNo = "KD00000014";
            zMethodObj.IPlant = "1001";
            zMethodObj.ITripNo = "1001201406140027";
            zMethodObj.IVhclNo = "AP29Q8639";

            zMethodResobj = zClassobj.ZbapiFiCreateInternalOrder(zMethodObj);
```

but at last line i got "underlying connection established was closed. unexpected format was send" error.

please help me...

Comment: This looks to me like a question for SAP developers you're working with. Try using Fiddler and capture the data if possible

Answer (score 2):

I'm actually using a soap service for a SAP WebService and I think I know what the problem is. You have to do first a Request including the QaaWsHeader and the ReportBlock configuration, then create the Request and finally with help with the ServicesSoapClient make the method to send your result.

Use this as an example, I hope this will help, good luck

```
Sellers.QaaWSHeader qaawsHeaderDatos = new Sellers.QaaWSHeader();
Sellers.GetReportBlock_WBS_Sellers getReportBlock = new Sellers.GetReportBlock_WBS_Sellers();
getReportBlock.login = userWS;
getReportBlock.password = passWS;
getReportBlock.refresh = true;
getReportBlock.startRow = 0;
getReportBlock.startRowSpecified = true;
getReportBlock.endRow = 1000;
getReportBlock.endRowSpecified = true;
Sellers.GetReportBlock_WBS_Sellers_Request WSRequest = new Sellers.GetReportBlock_WBS_Sellers_Request(qaawsHeaderDatos, getReportBlock);

Sellers.BIServicesSoap BiService = new Sellers.BIServicesSoapClient();
Sellers.GetReportBlock_WBS_Sellers_Response FinalResponse = BiService.GetReportBlock_WBS_Sellers(WSRequest);
object[][] yourTable = FinalResponse.table;
```