# How to get Purchase Order and Status from SAP

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, sap-erp, sap-dotnet-connector

NET 4.5.x in an ASP MVC app and looking for help on retrieving the purchase order. I have access to the .NET Connector, but not I am getting an exception.

I looked at the following:

1. saw this [link on SO about consuming webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24490998/how-to-consume-sap-web-service-in-c-sharp?rq=1),
2. I saw the/tried the SAP DI site, it wont let me access, asking me for a partner number for documentation?
3. I also saw this [code project site](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18909/Transferring-Data-from-SAP-to-NET-using-ERPConnect), its out of date and does not have the PO objects

Can someone please share where to start with SAP? How can I get the Purchase Orders for SAP? What DLL or connector is the current version?

1. Which table/object give me the purchase orders?
2. I would like to get a list of PO's
3. Give SAP a PO and how to get the status of a PO

*I tried this with the old connector based on the links above...*

```
 if (oDeliveryNote.Add == 0)  {
  Documents tmpDel = vCmp.GetBusinessObject(BoObjectTypes.oDeliveryNotes);
   //Then using the GetByKey method together with the GetNewObjectKey method,
   //we can get info about the newly created PO 

  if (tmpDel.GetByKey(vCmp.GetNewObjectKey)) {
    //Let's populate some variables that we declared earlier
    DelNr = tmpDel.DocNum;
    NumAtcard = tmpDel.NumAtCard;
    CardCode = tmpDel.CardCode;
    DocType = tmpDel.UserFields.Fields.Item("U_type").Value;
   }
  }
```

thanks

Comment: I think the tables involved should be EKKO and EKPO assuming only standard tables used. You should consider posting to SCN as well.

Comment: @shree.pat18 can you please tell me do I need both, on the SCN connectors link it says authorization needed even after registering. Which one will give me the current list of open PO's please

Comment: EKKO is headers, EKPO is line items so depends what you want to retrieve. You can try searching for SAP PO BAPI or similar to see what methods you need to use.

Comment: Your code for POs doesn't make sense. Exactly what are you trying here? My suggestion: Google "The NetWeaver Enterprise Procurement Model" and get yourself a trial account to start consuming POs via that model. It's a demo model to help you understand what's going on.

Comment: @shree.pat18 thanks that helped me with a start... never new EKPO was PO! Gosh SAP is convoluted

Comment: @MikaelG that snippet was to *add* a PO using the connector 1.8 and 2.0, using that would mean I have to downgrade the entire project to an older runtime for the old connector. The search was very helpful it goes fairly deep into procurement and MM. I was asked to simply get the list of PO's from the SAP system. Whoever previously implemented left, and the vendor now wants the PO's in the outside system